# When button is clicked, the div jumps out of place

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

## Problem

When I click the buttons for playoff season or regular, the divs that holds the content `players-list` and `players-regular` appear to jump out of place when they fade in and out. How do I prevent this from happening?

I've tried using position fixed on some of elements, but things would get way out of place. I've included a JSFiddle here: **http://jsfiddle.net/onlyandrewn/gcthaffs/**

### Click listener

```
 // Click listener, toggles between sheets
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('button').removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

        if ($('button.regular').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#players-list').fadeOut(500);
            $('.note').fadeOut(500);
            $('#players-regular').fadeIn(2000);
        } else {
            $('#players-regular').fadeOut(500);
            $('#players-list').fadeIn(2000);
            $('.note').fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });
```

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Wheat Kings' leading point scorers</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Wheat Kings' leading point scorers">
    <meta name="author" content="Andrew Nguyen">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Wheat Kings leading goal scorers</h1>
    <p class="year"></p>
    <button class="playoffs active">Playoffs</button>
    <button class="regular">Regular Season</button>

    <div class="top">
        <div id="players-list"></div>
        <div id="players-regular"></div>

        <p class="note">Note: Since there was a five-way tie for 6th place, players who scored two goals were then ranked by their total points in the playoffs. The other two players not listed here are Nolan Patrick and Macoy Erkamps.</p>
    </div><!-- /.top -->

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tabletop.js/1.3.5/tabletop.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/3.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>

    <!-- This is where the template for facts goes -->
    <script id="players" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="group">
                <div class="{{row}}">
                    <p class="goals">{{goals}}</p>
                    <img src="{{image}}" alt="" class="head">
                    <p class="name">{{name}}</p>
                    <p class="position">{{position}}</p>
                </div><!-- /.group -->
            </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.container -->
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // Click listener, toggles between sheets
    $('button').click(function() {
        $('button').removeClass("active");
        $(this).toggleClass("active");

        if ($('button.regular').hasClass('active')) {
            $('#players-list').fadeOut(500);
            $('.note').fadeOut(500);
            $('#players-regular').fadeIn(2000);
        } else {
            $('#players-regular').fadeOut(500);
            $('#players-list').fadeIn(2000);
            $('.note').fadeIn(2000);
        }
    });

      // Original
      var public_spreadsheet_url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RMN49oyRlTxW5kv8MnYJwQRttis2csgVFH46kyORCaQ/pubhtml";

      $(document).ready( function() {
        Tabletop.init( { key: public_spreadsheet_url,
            callback: showInfo,
            parseNumbers: true } );
      });
      function showInfo(data, tabletop) {
        var source   = $("#players").html();
        var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

        // The actual name of the sheet, not entire .csv
        $.each(tabletop.sheets("Playoffs").all(), function(i, fact) {
            var html = template(fact);

          // You need an element with this id or class in your HTML
          $("#players-list").append(html);
          $('.container').eq(i).addClass(data.Playoffs.elements[i]);

          // This logs all the objects in the sheet
          // console.log(data);

          // This logs just validity
          // console.log(data.Playoffs.elements[i]);
      })

        // If you need to get data from a second sheet in single Google Doc
        $.each(tabletop.sheets("Regular").all(), function(i, fact) {
            var html = template(fact);

          // You need an element with this id or class in your HTML
          $("#players-regular").append(html);
          $('.container').eq(i).addClass(data.Regular.elements[i]);

          // This logs all the objects in the sheet
          // console.log(data);

          // This logs just validity
          // console.log(data.Regular.elements[i]);
      });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

### base.scss

```
/*----------------------------------
MAIN STYLES
----------------------------------*/

html {
  font-size: 62.5%; /* 10px browser default */
}

body {
    max-width: 600px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.top {
    max-width: 600px;
}

#players-list,
#players-regular {
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.note {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    left: 3%;
}
```

Comment: Works fine in Chrome

Comment: Works fine in nightly firefox

Comment: If you minimize the screen size in the JSFiddle by `CMD -`, you'll see it jump. I tried to solve the problem with `position: fixed` but I didn't have much luck.

Comment: What browser are you using? Latest FF is fine.

Comment: @PavelPájaHalbich I'm using Chrome Canary.

Comment: I think it has to do with how you are displaying them. I dont know what you are using to fade the images in but you are basically making one display before the other one has completely been displayed none; you are adjusting the opacity but the block is still there so the other on gets turn on then replaces the position of the other when it is gone;

Comment: @Enjayy I've added the code for the jQuery FadeIn/FadeOut in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because the fadeOut is not done when the fadeIn starts. You end up with both divs visible for a short period of time, and when the fadeOut is done the first div is hidden and you see the jump.

How about something like this:

```
$('#players-list').fadeOut(500, function() {
     $('#players-regular').fadeIn(500);
 });
```

This way the second div is displayed only when the first one is completely hidden.
Also, decrease the animation duration a bit, it makes for better user experience ;).

Comment: Good call on user experience. Whole second for animation is a lot